# Problem with jquery fadeIn() fadeOut() animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm creating a filterable gallery so the user can select the category and the gallery will show the images only of that category.

I want to change the image on hover and this was very simple. Now I'm trying to add animation for changing the image so I want that the old image will fadeOut and then change the image and after changing the image fadeIn.

I have also achieved that but there is an error that I'm unable to figure out. This works fine for only the first time then the animation executes one more time. For example when I hover the second time the animation works 2 times and if I hover a 4th time the animation work 4 times.

```
$('.product_image').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).fadeOut('fast', function() {  
    $(this).attr('src', 'www.mydomain.com/img/default.jpg').fadeIn();
  });

  $('.product_image').mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut('fast', function() { 
      $(this).attr('src', 'realimage').fadeIn();
    });
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is because the `mouseleave` event is nested within the `mouseenter`, so you're adding a new event handler each time.

To fix this, separate the event handlers:

```js
$('.product_image').mouseenter(function() {
  $(this).fadeOut('fast', function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'www.mydomain.com/img/default.jpg').fadeIn();
  });
});

$('.product_image').mouseleave(function() {
  $(this).fadeOut('fast', function() {
    $(this).attr('src', 'realimage').fadeIn();
  });
});
```

Note that you can also make this a little more succinct by using `on()` from a single jQuery object:

```
$('.product_image').on({
  mouseenter: function() {
    $(this).fadeOut('fast', function() {
      $(this).attr('src', 'www.mydomain.com/img/default.jpg').fadeIn();
    });
  },
  mouseleave(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut('fast', function() {
      $(this).attr('src', 'realimage').fadeIn();
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I have tried also like this but then the realimage variable is empty in mousleave function. Because i create it on mouseenter.

Comment: How? Your question does not display that logic. However, I'd suggest using `data` attributes on the element to store the image URLs instead

Comment: Good idea i'll try it and i'll let you know. Thanks